# Using maps in offline

Tags: android, gps, maps

Is it possible to use maps in offline without GPS being turned on? Does it require any third party libraries?
I tried https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid but it's giving me some kind of errors.

Comment: You can use maps from Google. It doesn't require GPS being turned on.

Comment: If you're asking about Google Maps, offline maps was supported for a moment, but Google pulled it back. As for general answer, you have to use 3rd-party library for offline maps, like OSMDroid. In general, maps applications shouldn't need GPS to work.